# Prevent direct access to uploads folder for non-loggedin user (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to prevent non-logged in user to direct access from uploads folder inside wp-content. I have tried by putting the following rules in htaccess.conf in the AWS Lightsail server. After that, it's working fine but the site is broken now. Can anyone help me to figure out why it's broken? When I remove the rules from htaccess.conf the site loads fine.

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/">
# Protect all files within the uploads folder
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)wp-content/uploads/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: In what way is the site broken? What happens when you try to access it? Please add some more info to the question.

Comment: It seemed all CSS isn't loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it, So basically I need to prevent the direct access to a folder which is inside the wp-content/uploads folder. So I just created .htaccess files inside that folder and put following rules and it's working fine now. Thanks all

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have tried this, it's the same and I am not using any file called dl-file.php

Comment: @AbdullahAlFaruk which WP version you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest version which is 5.4. I am getting this type of broken page in the dashboard after putting these rules - https://prnt.sc/rvaa8o and front end is totally white

Comment: Clearly an unfinished answer pulled from:
https://carlofontanos.com/restrict-access-to-wp-contentuploads-when-user-is-not-logged-in/